# SQL UNION result not the same as the result of individual statements?

Tags: sql

Is it possible for UNION of two sql statements to produce an output that is different from output of executing each of the two statements separately?

Comment: No. A union combines two alike queries. Nothing more nothing less

Comment: @Elias . . . Your comment is incorrect.  `union` removes duplicates.  That would fall under the category of "more".

Comment: @Elias it removes duplicate rows unless you use `UNION ALL`

Comment: @GordonLinoff wouldn't removing duplicates make it "less"? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Absolutely.

The `union` removes duplicates.  If you want the same results, use `union all`.

Also note:  the ordering after `union` and `union all` is not guaranteed.  If you want things in a particular order, use `order by`.

Comment: Agreed, but should probably also call out that a `UNION ALL` statement will return an output that is indential, in content and not necessarily in order, to running the two queries seperately.